# How to Retrieve value of maximum occurance of a char column

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have issues in obtaining the maximum occurance of a column

```
 matnum   uom  amount
-------------------------------------
1234    EA   10
1234    CS   10
1234    EA    20
1235    CS   10
1235    CS    20
```

---

my output selection should be

```
 matnum   uom  SUM(amount)
-------------------------------------
1234   EA (because EA occured Twice)    40
1235   CS                               30
```

---

kindly provide a select query to obtain the desired result

Comment: what is the correct value of `1234`, is it supposed to be 40 or 30?  If `EA` occurs twice then the total appears to be 30 but you show that you want 40?

Comment: Your title says maximum but the required output might be the sum - Which of max or sum do you mean? As @Bluefeet says they are not the cirrect totals

Comment: I'm guessing `uom` and `SUM(amount)` are not related. `SUM(amount)` appears to be the sum for all rows in `matnum` and `uom` appears to be the most frequent value. Definitely not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a few things here about what you want, but:

```
SELECT A.matnum, B.uom, C.s AS [SUM(amount)]
FROM yourtable A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT matnum, uom, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY matnum ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnm
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY matnum, uom
) B ON A.matnum = B.matnum AND B.rnm = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT matnum, SUM(amount) AS s 
    FROM yourtable 
    GROUP BY matnum
) C ON A.matnum = C.matnum
GROUP BY A.matnum, B.uom, C.s
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1c54/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select matnum, 
       uom, 
       SUM(amount) as sum_amount
from your_table
group by matnum, uom
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(matnum) as matnum,max(uom) as uom,SUM(amount)
from yourtable
group by matnum,uom
```